# Why does GCC inline assembler require you to specify input/output both by position and by constraint?

Tags: gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

GCC inline assembler requires you to list input and output constraints separately.  But then it also requires you to specify "=" before an output constraint, which according to [the manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Modifiers.html) means that "this operand is write-only."  No modifier means read-only.  Now, there seems to me that there is a subtle difference between read-only/write-only and input/output, and that therefore these are treated differently.  But how does gcc practically distinguish between "input" and "read-only" if they are not identical?  Are there any cases where one would put an "=" on an input constraint, or omit it on an output constraint?  For "+" (both read and written) parameters, is there a difference in putting this parameter in the input vs. the output section?  Is there a difference between specifying a parameter as a "+" constraint vs. specifying it as follows?

```
"some instruction" : "=r" : 0 :
```

Answer (score 4):

The texinfo manual for gcc-4.7.2 states that the '=' is mandatory for output constraints, and that '+' in an output operand means that it could also be an input. The rules are somewhat complex, read the manual carefully.

As I understand it, '=' on an input makes no sense (a *written only* **input**?!). If an input is modified, list it as output (there might be several!), perhaps associating it to a junk variable, and tie it with the output by a number constraint.

Yes, this is all rather confusing. The constraints come from the internal language GCC uses to describe operations, and have evolved over time (with some backwards compatibility thrown it for spice). Adopt some style, and stick to it. Remember that the compiler treats your `asm()` snippet as a black box, to be copied by replacing arguments where told and nothing else, much like preprocessor macros are handled. It *doesn't* check if your instruction's addressing modes make sense, if the instructions are for your current machine, nothing. Just text to be macro-exanded and copied into the assembly output. Check carefully that you are saying what you mean (hopefully as liberal as the instruction's addressing modes allow, you don't want the compiler to go through contortions to comply with unneded restrictions; but not allowing something the instruction doesn't handle). Check the generated assembly!

Comment: Thanks.  I'm actually not so sure that "written only input" makes no sense.  In one way to understand the asm model (which the question is whether this is correct), "input" means allocate something to move things to before the assembly, and "output" means allocate something to move things from after the assembly.  So it might actually be more correct, for example, to list a memory location which is written to as a written-only input.  But nobody does it that way, so that's probably wrong.

Comment: You say "The constraints come from the internal language GCC uses to describe operations, and have evolved over time (with some backwards compatibility thrown it for spice)" but I think that's the problem I'm trying to get at with this question. "Internal languages" that you supposedly don't need to know about have here bled out into the way one accesses the assembler, and I worry that, not understanding that internal language, my code may break with a future (or past!) compiler even if it compiles how I intend today.